# HTTPS get using Jython

Tags: python, ssl, urllib2, jython

Please see my code below. Basically it's a script that queries an API service with a hostname as the parameter, which then returns some meta data associated with this server. Now, it works really well when executed from a `Python 2.7` compiler that's been installed into a windows machine, also works using `CURL` from a bash CLI (meaning that the URL is definitely working), but this script will be running on an HP application that has an embedded JVM wrapper, meaning that it will use `Jython` and not `CPython` like my local machine - at least that's what I think the issue is. This is what causes the first problem - SSL handshake will fail because while CPython ignores certificates, Jython doesn't. Since the certificate of this internal API is self-signed, I get this:

```
jvm 1    | sslerror(-1, 'SSL handshake exception: Differences between the SSL socket behaviour of cpython vs. jython are explained on the wiki:  http://wiki.python.org/jython/NewSocketModule#SSL_Support')
```

When attempted using HTTP, I get error code 400:

```
400: ('Bad Request', 'Bad request syntax or unsupported method')
```

I think it's worth noting that it cannot be a network problem. I can get the data from the browser using HTTP just fine.

Ideally, I would be happy with unsecure HTTP since it's an internal service anyway. Also, trusting certs is going to be problematic since my script will run in 45-50 different machines, adding way too much overhead.

Also, using something other than urllib2 (Python requests module, for example) is going to be a problem, because anything non-ootb would have to be distributed to all the machines, again adding unacceptable overhead.

I have found this: [trusting all certificates in Jython](http://tech.pedersen-live.com/2010/10/trusting-all-certificates-in-jython/), but frankly I don't understand much.

I guess my question is: why HTTP fails?

EDIT: Imported some certs into JVM's keystore, now I seem to be passing the SSL layer but it still responds with code 400.

```
import urllib2
import base64
baseUrl = 'https://my-api-example.com/'
hostname = 'server1.example.com'
username = "vinnie"
password = 'pooh'
request = urllib2.Request(baseUrl + hostname)
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password))
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
try:
    data = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    print data.read()
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.code
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print e.reason
except:
    print 'Undefined error'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out by myself by printing out the properties of the "request" instance. Doing so revealed that base64.encode apparently returns the string with a trailing newline symbol, which causes the server to respond with 400. I guess using encode would have bypassed the issue, although I can't understand why base64.encode gives the value back with a trailing newline in the first place.

Case closed...