# <urlopen error (-1, 'SSL exception: Differences between the SSL socket behaviour of cpython vs. jython are explained on the wiki

Tags: python, ssl, jython

I'm using the following code.

```
import urllib2

#Setting proxy
myProxy = {'https':'https://proxy.example.com:8080'}
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler(myProxy)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

#Access URL
auth_token = "realLy_loNg_AuTheNicaTion_toKen"
headers={"Content-Type":"application/json",
         "charset": "UTF-8",
         "Authorization": "Bearer %s" %auth_token}
url = "https://example.com/something"
req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
reply = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print reply.getcode()
```

I'm running the above as a Jython script in nGrinder. When I run the same script on my system with Jython, it works fine and returns 200(OK status code). When I run it on nGrinder, I get the error

```
(-1, 'SSL exception: Differences between the SSL socket behaviour of cpython vs. jython are explained on the wiki:  http://wiki.python.org/jython/NewSocketModule#SSL_Support')
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT: I've been trying and the issue is definitely with the long authentication token. I have a feeling it might be some encoding issue. There was a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912074/https-get-using-jython) before. I read it but it wasn't described properly. But it could be a good reference to think off of.

Comment: Do you need any of the features listed at the URL given?

Comment: No, I'm simply checking the status code of the URL

Comment: Looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912074/https-get-using-jython), can you print the Request's `data` and `origin_req_host` attribute? This may help us debug.

Comment: While this was working with the Jython interpreter on my system, it seems that Grinder was processing it differently. Used in-built grinder HTTP functions and re-wrote the code. Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you also using base64encoding for authtoken? ALthough from code it doesn't seems like but as you mentioned it is similar to one you have referred in link. Also can you provide difference in versions of both, environmental difference if any?

Comment: No, I am not @Naruto

Answer (score 0):

It seems issue of certificate trust.
http://bugs.jython.org/issue1688

There are these two options that will solve your problem.

> Jython is not like cpython. Cpython does not verify the chain of trust
>   for server certificates. Jython does verify the chain of trust, and
>   will refuse to open the connection if it cannot verify the server.
>
> So you have two options.
>
> 1. Disable certificate checking on jython
>
> http://jython.xhaus.com/installing-an-all-trusting-security-provider-on-java-and-jython/
>   http://tech.pedersen-live.com/2010/10/trusting-all-certificates-in-jython/
>
> 2. Add your (self-signed?) certificate to your local java trust store, so that your client will trust your server.
>
> Google("java install self-signed certificate")

Another reason for this can be due to incompactible version of python and java (https://github.com/geoscript/geoscript-py/issues/32)

> I just tried with Jython 2.5.3 and JDK 1.7 on Mac and was able to run
>   ez_setup.py.
>
> Java version: [Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)]
>   on java1.7.0_51
>
> Swapping to Oracle JDK 7 did the trick.

Please check if this solves the problem, as per implementation of jython and error, issue is due to HTTPS(SSL layer) https://github.com/int3/jython/blob/master/Lib/socket.py

```
# These error codes are currently wrong: getting them correct is going to require
# some investigation. Cpython 2.6 introduced extensive SSL support.

(javax.net.ssl.SSLException, ALL)                        : lambda x: sslerror(-1, 'SSL exception'+_ssl_message),
```